# UIAccessibilityTrait adjustable does not enter increment() or decrement() swift

Tags: swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have an element (an imageView) which shows a number. 
I want the voice over user to swipe up to increment and swipe down to decrement.
There are a total of six numbers (images) and each number shoes different content on screen.

For that intent I made the view adjustable:

`imageView.accessibilityTraits = .adjustable`

I also implemented the following methods:

```
override func accessibilityIncrement() {
    print("increment")
}

override func accessibilityDecrement() {
    print("decrement")
}
```

However, when I test this, Xcode won't go inside the increment or decrement methods.

What am I making wrong? Is there maybe a better way to increment or decrement a value using voice over?

Comment: Where have you implemented the two accessibility methods ?

Comment: in the imageView's superview, where I set `imageView.isAccessibilityElement = true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you implemented the `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()` methods in your view controller but they should belong to the created image view whose trait should be `.adjustable`.

Just subclass `UIImageView` as follows in this basic example:

```
class MyImageView: UIImageView {

    override var isAccessibilityElement: Bool {
        get { return true }
        set { }
    }

    override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
        get { return .adjustable }
        set { }
    }

    override func accessibilityIncrement() {
        print("INCREMENT")
    }

    override func accessibilityDecrement() {
        print("DECREMENT")
    }
}
```

You just have to define what to do in each adjustable method and that should do the job.

I suggest you take a look at [this site](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#continuous-adjustable-values) where a complete example about adjustable values with code snippets and illustrations is provided for both ObjC and Swift.